# creating a threadless task using Taskcompletion source

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am getting my hands dirty with TPL.I stumbled upon a topic in TPL called TaskCompletionSource which is one of the ways to create a Task and it give you more control over the task by allowing developers in setting result,exception etc etc. Here is an example using task completion source

```
   public static Task<int> RunAsyncFunction(Func<int> sampleFunction)
    {
        if (sampleFunction == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("Method cannot be null");

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        {
            try
            {
                int result = sampleFunction();
                tcs.SetResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

However this is not truly asynchronus programming.It is asynchronus programming using multithreading .How can I convert this example to get it run on a single thread rather than multiple threads ? or is there any other example I can follow?

Answer (score 3):

For it to be asynchronous, it needs some capacity to be completed independently in the future. That is typically via one of two things:

- via a callback from an operation such as socket IO, file IO, a system timer, etc (some external source that can cause reactivation)
- a second thread (possibly a queued work pool thread, like in your example)

If you only have a single thread, and no external callback, then there really isn't any need or sense in using `Task<T>`. However, you can still expose that by simply performing the calculation now, and setting the result now - or more simply: using `Task.FromResult`.

However, the code you have shown *is* genuinely asynchronous - or more specifically: the `Task<T>` that you return is. It perhaps isn't the greatest use-case, but there's nothing *inherently* wrong with it - except that your entire method can be hugely simplified to:

```
return Task.Run(sampleFunction);
```

The [`Task.Run<T>` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task or Task handle for that work.

Normally, if I'm using `TaskCompletionSource`, it is because I am writing IO-callback based tasks, not `ThreadPool` based tasks; `Task.Run` is fine for most of those.

Comment: Hi Marc...so is TaskCompletionSource<T> the only way to create threadless base task ???

Comment: @kyle at the implementation level, yes; however, if the thing you are talking to already has a `Task`-based async API, you can often use `async`/`await` to compose more complex logic  via continuations; the compiler then provides most of the details for you.

Answer (score 1):

TaskCompletionSource doesn't make your code asynchronous. It's a utility to enable someone else to asynchronously await your operation.

Your operation needs to already be asynchronous on its own. For example if it's in an older paradigm, like the BeginXXX/EndXXX one.

TaskCompletionSource is mostly used to convert different types of asynchronous programming into Task based asynchronous programming.

Comment: If you have BeginXXX/EndXXX you can wrap the method with microsoft's utility methods https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Gusdor sure, because it's common. The point is that if you needed to implement that method you would use TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: Consider my comment an addendum for those who don't know :-)

Comment: @Gusdor of course. You can also edit it in if you like.